# What are "Location" and "Repositories" in the VisualSVN?

Tags: svn, repository, visualsvn-server

I am trying to install VisualSVN to manage my code with other users. In the middle of the installation I have a window saying "Change if necessary installation path and initial VisualSVN Server setting". And after that (in the same window) I have two fields: "Location" and "Repositories". What these two parameters mean?

I know URL where the common code is stored. Should I specify this URL in the "repositories" field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, "Location" is the directory the actual VisualSVN executable will be installed in (It's preset to `C:\Program Files`, right?)

The "Repositories" path is the physical path to the Repositories directory. VisualSVN (or rather, the underlying svn server) will store all repositories there. This can be a directory located anywhere you want; as it contains the actual working data, it shold be backed up.

Are you totally sure you're installing the right product though? From this:

> I know URL where the common code is stored.

I thought it could be you just need a subversion *client*, not a full *server*?

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/ it looks unlikely that you'll be able use the URL for the repository. It looks to me like VisualSVN is expecting a path to a repository on disk.